# Insert empty paragraph using insertHtml

Tags: java, html, aspose, aspose.words

I try to fill a document in aspose words java (v.20.6) using DocumentBuilder and insertHtml.
But when i insert empty paragraphs they are ignored in word.
Is it not possible to insert empty paragraphs with insertHtml?

Example:

```
Document doc = new Document("tmp.docx");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.moveToBookmark("Text", false, false);
builder.insertHtml("<p>Before empty paragraph</p><p></p><p>After empty paragraph</p>", true);
doc.save("C:/TMP/doc.docx");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty paragraphs in HTML are ignored by Aspose.Words to mimic MS Word and browsers behavior. If you open the following HTML in any browser you will not see an empty paragraph.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <p>Before empty paragraph</p><p></p><p>After empty paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if you open it in MS Word you will notice that there is no empty paragraph too.
[image]

But if add non-breaking space, the empty paragraph is there.
[image]

So there are two options to keep an empty paragraph, either put non-breaking space into the empty paragraph in your HTML string

```java
builder.insertHtml("<p>Before empty paragraph</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>After empty paragraph</p>", true);
```

or use DocumentBuilder.writeln method

```java
builder.insertHtml("<p>Before empty paragraph</p>", true);
builder.writeln();
builder.insertHtml("<p>After empty paragraph</p>", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why i have to put an &nbsp; in the paragraph. But it works.

Comment: @BenjaminSchüller I updated my answer to explain the behavior.